# how to make an input date field greater than or equal to another date field using validation in laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hi iam developing an application using laravel is there any way to make an input date field greater than or equal to another date field using validation.

I know that i can achieve this through jquery and i have already got that working, but i want to know whether is this achievable through laravel validation since laravel has got some predefined validations.

For Example

```
protected $validationRules = array
    (   
      'a' => 'date',
      'b' => 'date|(some validation so that the b value is greater than or equal to that of 'a')'
    );
```

**EDIT**

If there is any other approach to solve the problem using laravel concept please tell me

**I tried**

```
Validator::extend('val_date', function ($attribute,$value,$parameters) {
    return preg_match("between [start date] and DateAdd("d", 1, [end date])",$value);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem. `before` and `after` does not work when dates could be the same. Here is my short solution:

**NOTE:** Laravel 5.3.25 and later have new built in rules: [`before_or_equal`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-before-or-equal) and [`after_or_equal`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-after-or-equal)

---

```
// 5.1 or newer
Validator::extend('before_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) >= strtotime($value);
});

// 5.0 & 4.2
Validator::extend('before_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return strtotime(Input::get($parameters[0])) >= strtotime($value);
});
```

---

```
$rules = array(
    'start'=>'required|date|before_or_equal:stop',
    'stop'=>'required|date',
);
```

---

Comment: Note this does not work for Laravel 5.2 See my answer.

Comment: Where do you put the first block of code? In your controller?

Comment: @user3253002 You can put the first block of code in a [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers)

Comment: Where does this go in Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 8):

Emil Aspman's answer is correct, but doesn't work for Laravel 5.2. this solution works for Laravel 5.2:

```
 Validator::extend('before_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
     return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) >= strtotime($value);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `after:date` or `before:date` like this:

```
protected $rules = array(
    'date' => 'after:'.$yourDate
);
```

or alternatively

```
protected $rules = array(
    'date' => 'before:'.$yourDate
);
```

It will do exactly what you described. Also check out the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-before).
You can also specify rules of your own using [custom validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: thanks for your reply i hope after:date will allow only dates after the specified date i need validation rule to satisfy both after and same rule so that my date field will allow both same and after date but not before date. I also tried 'date' => 'after:'.$yourDate, but it throws the following error:- [syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')']

Comment: `after` and `before` do not allow equality when times are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution would be if you extended the Validator with your own rule. A simple example from the docs:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

Read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: i read the documentation but iam not sure how to write the expression to satisfy my condition i have updated my question with what i have tried please take a look.