# after_or_equal validation does not work in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to compare start_date with end_date , 
and end_date should be equal or greater then start_date,
i am using after_or_equal validation.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
      'start_date' => 'required',
      'end_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:start_date'
]);


after_or_create validation of laravel5.2 return error like this.
Method [validateAfterOrEqual] does not exist.
```

Comment: what is your laravel version

Comment: you need to upgrade your version to 5.4 to use after_or_equal

Comment: Thanks for replay,I can't update my version so how can i resolve my problem without upgrading version ?

Comment: try to write your custom validation . refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018045/how-to-make-an-input-date-field-greater-than-or-equal-to-another-date-field-usin

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade your version to 5.4 to use `after_or_equal`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-after-or-equal

**Note :** `after_or_equal` is available from version `laravel 5.3`

Answer (score 0):

Validator::extend('before_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) { return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) >= strtotime($value); });
  Or alternative is upgrade to 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Simply send your date back by 1 day and use the after: rule!

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days');

$rule = ['start_date' => 'required|after:'.$yesterday];
```

This will work for all versions of laravel as long as the after: or before: rules are there.